# How can I remove an unwanted Just Join app from Mac.?

Tags: mac

Trying to remove Just.join app. without success message states "can't be removed because it's open" when I tried to open it states"can't open because it may be damaged".
can anybody tell me how to proceed please.
System High Sierra (10.13.6

Comment: Have you tried starting in Safe Boot and trying the delete then?

Answer (score 1):

Open Activity Monitor and force the app to quit. If you still can’t remove it you might need to use a safe boot or safe log in holding shift when you boot or shift when you enter your password to log in again to prevent the app from starting.